# How to upload PHAsset (video and image only)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, phasset

I want to upload PHAsset but I do not have the file path of the asset. I am able to upload the file using the below block methods. But these are asynchronous methods to get the URLs. Is there any synchronous method to do so or any other way to upload the PHAsset files.

Image Asset URL:

```
[asset requestContentEditingInputWithOptions:editOptions
                               completionHandler:^(PHContentEditingInput *contentEditingInput, NSDictionary *info) {
        NSURL *imageURL = contentEditingInput.fullSizeImageURL;
    }];
```

Video file URL:

```
[[PHImageManager defaultManager]requestAVAssetForVideo:asset options:nil resultHandler:^(AVAsset * _Nullable asset, AVAudioMix * _Nullable audioMix, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {

                    NSURL *url = (NSURL *)[[(AVURLAsset *)asset URL] fileReferenceURL];




                }];
```

Comment: We have to deal with these asynchronous methods. And also take into account for the files whose URL is nil. Such files are not present on the local device and instead present on the iCloud.

Answer (score 6):

I am fetching video from PHAsset and storing that to local file path to upload it to server: here is the following code:

```
let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key:"creationDate",ascending:false)]
assets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with:fetchOptions)

let resourceManager = PHAssetResourceManager.default()
let resource = PHAssetResource.assetResources(for: asset).first!
let name = resource.originalFilename
let videoLocalPath = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(name)

//Storing the resource to local temporary path    
resourceManager.writeData(for: resource, toFile: videoLocalPath, options: nil, completionHandler: {error in
        if error != nil{
//       on success do the upload using the local file path
        }
    })
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I thought the same. The reason is the app runs in a sandbox and you cannot really change or copy directly from the photos folder. I've searched on many places but it is what it is. You have to create a local copy and use it.