# Getting the url of a video (PHAsset) for video uploading - swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, video, phasset

I've created two different functions for uploading PHASSets to my backend -

the uploadImageAsset() uploads all of the assets that are images:

```
func uploadImageAsset(asset: PHAsset, projectRef: String) {
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let dbRef = db.collection("projects").document(projectRef)
    let manager = PHImageManager.default()
    let option = PHImageRequestOptions()
    option.isSynchronous = false
    option.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
    option.resizeMode = .exact
    option.version = .original
    option.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat
    let imageSize = CGSize(width: asset.pixelWidth, height: asset.pixelHeight)
    let uniqueImageID = NSUUID().uuidString
    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("project-images").child("\(uniqueImageID).jpeg")

    manager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: imageSize, contentMode: .aspectFill, options: option) { (image, info) in
        let uploadData = image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.6)
        storageRef.putData(uploadData!, metadata: nil, completion: {
            (metadata, error) in

            if error != nil {
                return
            } else {
                storageRef.getMetadata(completion: { (metadata, err) in
                    if let error = err {
                        print(error)
                    } else {
                        storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, err) in
                            if let error = err {
                                print(error)
                            } else {
                                self.imageURLs.append((url?.absoluteString)!)
                                dbRef.updateData(["image": self.imageURLs], completion: { (err) in
                                    if err != nil {
                                        print(err)
                                    } else {
                                        SVProgressHUD.dismiss(withDelay: 0.3)
                                        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                                    }
                                })
                            }
                        })
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    }
}
```

and the uploadProjectVideos() uploads all of the assets that are videos:

```
func uploadVideoAsset(asset: PHAsset, projectRef: String) {
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let dbRef = db.collection("projects").document(projectRef)
    let manager = PHImageManager.default()
    let option = PHVideoRequestOptions()
    option.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
    option.deliveryMode = PHVideoRequestOptionsDeliveryMode.highQualityFormat

    manager.requestAVAsset(forVideo: asset, options: option) { (video, videoAudio, nil) in
        let avurlAsset = video as! AVURLAsset
        let fileURL = avurlAsset.url.absoluteString as! URL
        let fileName = NSUUID().uuidString + ".mov"
        let uploadTask = Storage.storage().reference().child(fileName).putFile(from: fileURL, metadata: nil, completion: { (metaData, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Failed upload of video", error)
                return
            }

            Storage.storage().reference().child(fileName).downloadURL { (url, error) in
                self.imageURLs.append("\(url)")
                dbRef.updateData(["image": self.imageURLs], completion: { (err) in
                    if err != nil {
                        print(err)
                    } else {
                        SVProgressHUD.dismiss(withDelay: 0.3)
                        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    }
}
```

When it comes to uploading images, my function for that works perfectly. ***However, my function for uploading videos is returning nil.*** Videos aren't being uploaded to the backend at all.

This is my first time working with PHAssets and Im really confused as to how ***I can get the video url of a phasset and upload it***

Comment: are you sure avURLAsset.url.absoluteString as! URL works? can you check your fileURL and debug putFile it actually fetches the file from the specified file path

Comment: A PHAsset has no URL. Pure duplicate of many existing questions. See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Upload+video+PHAsset

Answer (score -2):

You can use the **requestAVAsset(forVideo:options:resultHandler:)** method as shown in the documentation: *https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phimagemanager/1616935-requestavasset*.
And here's a little handy extension originally made by @iMHitesh Surani, updated to swift by @diegomen:

```
extension PHAsset {

func getURL(completionHandler : @escaping ((_ responseURL : URL?) -> Void)){
    if self.mediaType == .image {
        let options: PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions = PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions()
        options.canHandleAdjustmentData = {(adjustmeta: PHAdjustmentData) -> Bool in
            return true
        }
        self.requestContentEditingInput(with: options, completionHandler: {(contentEditingInput: PHContentEditingInput?, info: [AnyHashable : Any]) -> Void in
            completionHandler(contentEditingInput!.fullSizeImageURL as URL?)
        })
    } else if self.mediaType == .video {
        let options: PHVideoRequestOptions = PHVideoRequestOptions()
        options.version = .original
        PHImageManager.default().requestAVAsset(forVideo: self, options: options, resultHandler: {(asset: AVAsset?, audioMix: AVAudioMix?, info: [AnyHashable : Any]?) -> Void in
            if let urlAsset = asset as? AVURLAsset {
                let localVideoUrl: URL = urlAsset.url as URL
                completionHandler(localVideoUrl)
            } else {
                completionHandler(nil)
            }
        })
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Above code will not work while uploading video/image url directly to server. First, fetch the video/image from PHAsset and then storing that to local file path to upload it to server. Please check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38381851/how-to-upload-phasset-video-and-image-only?